# Is there any way to completely customise superset front-end when installed in Virtual Environment?

Tags: apache-superset

Superset allows us to edit CSS, but this is restricted to only dashboards section. What if I want to completely customise superset-frontend, when installed inside Virtual Environment

When superset is installed inside Virtual Environment we don't find `superset/superset-frontend` folder and we can only see compiled/post-build JS and CSS files [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70024194/how-to-modify-css-in-apache-superset).

So is there any way to customise superset-frontend?, like:

- Install superset via Docker and Docker Compose and apply all our frontend changes there(under `superset/superset-frontend` folder)
- Compile `superset/superset-frontend` to generate compiled/post-build HTML, CSS and JS files
- Paste these compiled/post-build files inside `superset/static/assets` folder inside Virtual Environment

**NOTE:** I tried to apply CSS changes in compiled CSS files, but it is very difficult to make changes there it has almost 28,000+ lines of code in main CSS file and there are about 7-10 other CSS files

Comment: Can you have any idea for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you `pip install apache-superset`, there's no way to edit the frontend files. Superset is fundamentally a multi-component web application and most people customize & deploy the components using Docker, Kubernetes, or some other virtual container abstraction.

Having pre-built frontend code & assets is considered a **feature not a bug** for people who want to quickly `pip install apache-superset` to try it out locally. Frontend code needs to be compiled and translated to browser-compatible HTML/CSS/JS. Having editable / exposed frontend code for people installing Superset via pip means introducing extra friction here (because of the compilation process), especially since many Pythonistas aren't necessarily familiar with the frontend ecosystem (node / npm etc).

Comment: This answer is fundamentally important and not very well documented in the installation documentation.  see: https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch